# how do I test a void function with react-testing-library and jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've the following function:

```
  const groupReset = (val: string) => {
    const updatedFilters = selectedFilters.filter((filters) => filters.type !== val)
    if (updatedFilters.length === 0) {
      setSelectedFilters([])
      setSelectedFiltersReqObject(undefined)
    } else {
      setSelectedFilters(updatedFilters)
    }
  }
```

I doesn't return anything. Only updating the state variables. How do I test it?

TIA!

I tied to use jest.fn() but couldn't get a hang of it.

Comment: In general you don't test functions in React other than the component functions.  You should be testing on the observable dom (so in your case whatever effect setting the selected filters does) or at boundaries that need to be isolated from unit tests like network calls.

Comment: You would need to provide more context, like: when this function is called, what changes in rendered component does those state changes do. When testing compoonent you should test its behaviour. The test should behave and do the things that user would do via browser like clicking, typing etc. Then you should test for observerable changes like some text appearing or disappearing.